# override default jvm reuse value

Tags: hadoop, jvm, mapreduce, reusability

We have mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks setting as -1(i.e to have jvm reuse with no limit) in hadoop's mapred-site.xml . But i want to override this property in one of my mapred job. Is it possible to override this value to 1 only for one job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override any property which is not marked as final in respective configuration.xml file. To do this

1. Pass commandline argument to `-D property_name=value`.
2. Or by configuring in you mapred job by

   Configuration.set("property_name", "value");

Answer (score 0):

You could use **public void setNumTasksToExecutePerJvm(int numTasks)**. It allows us to set the number of tasks that a spawned task JVM should run before it exits